# Carregar scss a partir de arquivo js

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, webpack, scss

Estou trabalhando em um site estático, onde tenho a seguinte estrutura de diretórios:

```
/
  /src
    exemplo.scss
    exemplo.js
  index.html
  webpack.config.js
```

No meu `exemplo.js` eu dou um `require('exemplo.scss')`, que por sua vez carrega o bootstrap. O webpack gera um arquivo `index.js`, neste arquivo consigo ver todas as classes do bootstrap (que foram carregadas a partir do `exemplo.scss`), mas as classes do bootstrap não são aplicadas no `index.html`.

Obs: `webpack`, `webpack-cli`, `bootstrap`, `css-loader`, `scss-loader` e etc. instalados. Não é gerado nenhum erro no console ou log. Estou importando o arquivo `index.js` gerado pelo webpack na minha `index.html`. É possível ver todas as classes do bootstrap no arquivo `index.js` gerado pelo webpack, mas não é possível usar as classes no `index.html`.

Answer (score 0):

Aposto que seu problema é com os pacotes que está instalando errado, você instalou `scss-lodaer` na verdade deveria ser `sass-loader`, e você precisa usar o `style-loader` junto.